# Data Binding issue with modular structuring of class

Tags: android, data-binding

Trying to modularise the app. Created module **B** from **base** module by moving commonly used files to **B**. Have moved a few classes which have databinding. While building the app the databinding is generated by *base package name* which should have generated by module **B** package name.

Base Module: com.package.app

Common Module: com.package.module

Getting below error in Common module binding:

error: cannot find symbol
import com.package.app.R;
                       ^

symbol:   class R
  location: package com.package.app

Comment: Did you move the XML layout files as well?

Comment: Yes, have moved the xml too

Comment: Thanks @Darwind Was able to resolve this. Supposedly there was once resource which wasn't yet moved but wasn't getting to the point which res neither was it mentioned in logs.

Comment: Awesome, that you fixed it :-) I didn't have any other suggestions anyways ;-)
The horrors of Databinding - the error messages are just not good enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve this. Supposedly there was once resource which wasn't yet moved but wasn't getting to the point which res neither was it mentioned in logs. Databinding sometimes surprises